# Remove Downloads section from Woocommerce order refunded email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email-notifications, digital-downloads

I have seen this snippet which removes from all customer emails, however I'm wondering how to remove the downloads section from the Woocommerce email: Order Refunded.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'remove_order_downloads_from_emails', 10, 1 ); 
function remove_order_downloads_from_emails( $emails ){
remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( $emails, 'order_downloads' ), 10 );
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following code will remove the downloads table section from Refunded order email notification:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'remove_downloads_section_from_refunded_order_emails', 1, 4 );
function remove_downloads_section_from_refunded_order_emails( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    if( $email->id === 'customer_refunded_order' )
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', array( WC()->mailer(), 'order_downloads' ), 10 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.